# Building a sparse matrix from another smaller matrix's values mapped by a logical array mask (MATLAB)?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix, adjacency-matrix

I am working with large sparse matrices ([sparse](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html)). I have a large sparse matrix of values which needs to be included into a larger sparse matrix. I have an array of `logicals` which indicates which rows and columns are to be filled up with the smaller matrix values. In this application the smaller of the two matrices is a graph stored as an adjacency matrix and the logicals indicate the node id positions in the larger matrix.

A small toy example to demonstrate what I am doing currently:

```
zz = sparse(4,4);  %create a sparse matrix of the final size desired
rr = rand(3,3);   %a matrix of values
logical_inds = logical([1 0 1 1]); %a logical array to index with the dimension size of zz
zz(logical_inds,logical_inds) = rr(:,:) %'rr' values are mapped into the subset of 'zz'
```

I see that the 2<sup>nd</sup> column of `zz` are zeros, and that the 2<sup>nd</sup> row are zero values as well. This is the output desired.

In my program  get a warning that this "sparse indexing is likely to be slow", and it is. Occasionally when the matrices are very large the program terminates at this line.

How can I create this matrix (`zz`) with the sparse method? I am unsure how to create the row column indexes from the mask of logicals I have, and how to turn the values of `rr` into an array ordered appropriately for this new indexing.

**in general `rr` is very sparse although the mask of logicals addresses the full matrix

Comment: Do you know the sizes of `rr` and `zz` beforehand, or are these only known at runtime? It could make a subtantial difference when you initialize `zz` using the `nzmax` argument

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis, only at run time they are known.

Comment: Interesting question. Does anyone have an idea why that code is slow?

Comment: @Vass: OK, so as a follow-up question, is the size of `rr` known before you have to create `zz`?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis, the size of `zz` is known first, then `rr`.

Comment: @LuisMendo My first thought would be that the logical indexing actually accesses the entire matrix? Definitely not sure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is mostly due to implicit resizing during the allocation. Here's why I think that:

```
%# test parameters
N  = 5000;               %# Size of 1 dimension of the square sparse
L  = rand(1,N) > 0.95;   %# 5% of rows/cols will be non-zero values
M  = sum(L);            
rr = rand(M);            %# the "data" to fill the sparse with 


%# Method 1: direct logical indexing
%# (your original method)
zz1 = sparse(N,N);    
tic    
    zz1(L,L) = rr;
toc

%# Method 2: test whether the conversion to logical col/row indices matters 
zz2  = sparse(N,N);    
inds = zz1~=0;    
tic        
    zz2(inds) = rr;
toc

%# Method 3: test whether the conversion to linear indices matters 
zz3 = sparse(N,N);
inds = find(inds);
tic        
    zz3(inds) = rr;
toc

%# Method 4: test whether implicit resizing matters    
zz4 = spalloc(N,N, M*M);
tic        
    zz4(inds) = rr;
toc
```

Results:

```
Elapsed time is 3.988558 seconds. %# meh   M1 (original)
Elapsed time is 3.916462 seconds. %# meh   M2 (expanded logicals)
Elapsed time is 4.003222 seconds. %# meh   M3 (converted row/col indices)
Elapsed time is 0.139986 seconds. %# WOW!  M4 (pre-allocated memory)
```

So apparently (and amazingly), it would seem that MATLAB does not grow the existing sparse *before* the allocation (as you'd expect), but actually loops through the row/col indices and grows the sparse *during* the iteration. Therefore, it would seem one has to "help" MATLAB a bit:

```
%# Create initial sparse
zz1 = sparse(N,N);    

%# ...
%# Do any further operations until you can create rr: 
%# ...

rr = rand(M);            %# the "data" to fill the sparse with 


%# Now that the size of the data is known, re-allocate space for the sparse:
tic
    [i,j] = find(zz1); %# indices
    [m,n] = size(zz1); %# Sparse size (you can also use N of course)
    zz1 = sparse(i,j,nonzeros(zz1), m,n, M*M);
    zz1(L,L) = rr; %# logical or integer indices, doesn't really matter 
toc
```

Results (for the same `N`, `L` and `rr`):

```
Elapsed time is 0.034950 seconds.  %# order of magnitude faster than even M4!
```

See also [this question+answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817806/best-practice-when-working-with-sparse-matrices).

Comment: @Vass: Well thanks! :) Did you try this on your case? Did it work?

Comment: yes it did work, fantastic! thought that it was a brick wall... I couldn't navigate your paypal coffee shop cause its in german^^, will find a german guy soon to help out! :D

Comment: @Vass: oh friggin' PayPal...I'll see if I can change it ^^

Comment: @Vass: Hmmm I see English...?

Answer (score 2):

To create this matrix with the `sparse` function the logical indices will need to be converted into row and column indices, **so this may end up being slower...**

Here the locations of ones in the logical vector are found and then a matrix is created containing the row and column indices for the non zeros in the sparse matrix.
Finally the sparse function is used to create the sparse matrix with the elements of `rr` in these locations (`rr(:)` is used to convert it into a column vector)

```
ind_locs = find(logical_inds);
ind = combvec(ind_locs,ind_locs);

zz = sparse(ind(1,:),ind(2,:),rr(:))
```

Comment: It appears this solution only operates on the relevant elements. Assuming sufficient sparsness I would expect good performance here.

Comment: Agreed, I nearly added a note on a similar track... I get a feeling for huge not very space matrices running `find` & creating the `ind` variable may be wasteful. (but if you have a huge not very sparse matrix then its probably the least of your worries)