# Is there overhead of accessing elements in a sparse matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix, overhead

Let's say I have a sparse matrix A. I want to do heavy calculations on it. The calculations do not modify A, only accessing its elements e.g. take a row of A then multiply with something. I wonder whether I should convert A to a full matrix before doing any calculation, or just do it directly?
In other words, is accessing elements in a sparse matrix slower than a full matrix?

Comment: If you have enough memory to convert `A` to `full`, why do you need `sparse` at all?

Comment: slicing sparse matrices across columns is much faster than by rows, which is understood given how the data is stored internally

Comment: @Luis: The server which i am working on has enough memory for it, but other users are using it as well so I think it would be nicer to use as less resource as possible. Also I did save that matrix (in sparse mode) into a mat file (it does save me some space). Now I load it back and wonder should I convert it to a full matrix.

Comment: @Amro +1: this is interesting. I just found the similar info in this link: http://www.mathengineering.com/understanding-sparse-matrix-storage

Comment: You might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817806/best-practice-when-working-with-sparse-matrices) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22868988/2338750), including the linked reference interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Slicing sparse matrices across columns is much faster than slicing across rows in MATLAB. So you should prefer accessing `M(:,i)` over `M(i,:)`.

Internally MATLAB uses the [Compressed Sparse Column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_column_.28CSC_or_CCS.29) (CSC) storage:

- the non-zero elements are stored in a 1-D double array of length `nzmax` arranged in [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order) (`pr` for real part and `pi` for imaginary part if matrix is complex)
- `ir` an array of integers with corresponding row indices
- `jc` an integer array of length `n+1` (where `n` is the number of columns) containing column index information. By definition, the last value of `jc` contains `nnz` (number of non-zeros stored).

As an example, take the following sparse matrix:

```
>> M = sparse([1 3 5 3 4 1 5], [1 1 1 2 2 4 4], [1 7 5 3 4 2 6], 5, 4);
```

This is what it looks like stored in memory (I'm using 0-based indices for `ir` and `jc`):

```
1 . . 2
. . . .
7 3 . .
. 4 . .
5 . . 6

pr = 1 7 5 3 4 2 6
ir = 0 2 4 2 3 0 4
jc = 0 3 5 5 7

nzmax = at least 7
nnz = 7
m = 5
n = 4
```

To retrieve the i-th column of the sparse matrix `M(:,i)`, it suffices to do: `pr(jc(i):jc(i+1)-1)` (to keep it simple, I'm not paying attention to 0- vs 1-based indexing). On the other hand, accessing a matrix row involves more calculations and array traversals (it is no longer [spatial-locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) friendly).

Here are some links to the MATLAB documentation for more info: [Sparse Matrices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/matlab-data.html#f47606), [Manipulating Sparse Matrices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/sparse-matrix-operations.html#f6-33247)

---

It's worth checking out the [original paper](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/otherdocs/simax.pdf) by *John R. Gilbert, Cleve Moler, and Robert Schreiber: "Sparse Matrices In Matlab: Design and Implementation", (SIAM Journal on Matrix Analysis and Applications , 13:1, 333–356 (1992))*.

Here are some quotes from the above paper to answer your question about the overhead of sparse storage:

> The computational complexity of simple array operations should be
>   proportional to `nnz`, and perhaps also depend linearly on `m` or `n`,
>   but be independent of the product `m*n`. The complexity of more
>   complicated operations involves such factors as ordering and fill-in,
>   but an objective of a good sparse matrix algorithm should be:
>
> > The time required for a sparse matrix operation should be proportional
> >     to number of arithmetic operations on nonzero quantities.
>
> We call this the "time is proportional to flops" rule; it is a
>   fundamental tenet of our design.

and

> This *(column-oriented sparse matrix)* scheme is not efficient
>   for manipulating matrices on element at a time: access to a single
>   element takes time at least proportional to the logarithm of the
>   length of its column; inserting or removing a nonzero may require
>   extensive data movement. However, element-by-element manipulation is
>   rare in MATLAB (and is expensive even in full MATLAB). Its most common
>   application would be to create a sparse matrix, but this is more
>   efficiently done by building a list `[i,j,s]` of matrix elements in
>   arbitrary order and then using `sparse(i,j,s)` to create the matrix.
>
> The sparse data structure is allowed to have unused elements after the
>   end of the last column of the matrix. Thus an algorithm that builds up
>   a matrix one column at a time can be implemented efficiently by
>   allocating enough space for all the expected nonzeros at the outset.

Also section 3.1.4 "asymptotic complexity analysis" should be of interest (it's too long to quote here).

Comment: although it does not answer my question (my question is to compare sparse matrix vs full matrix in term of retrieving elements), I am happy with this one.

Comment: To follow on from Amro's answer - if it really is rows you want from the sparse matrix - transpose it and extract columns from the transposed form. Or better still - use the profiler to see what's actually going on!